# no type arguments expected for fun getValue: Any?

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to implement a code sample from [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists) that **Listen for child events**,

```
val childEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {
override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.key!!)

    // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
    val comment = dataSnapshot.getValue<Comment>() // error line

    // ...
}
...
...
```

when i tried it for my firebase, Android studio hints an error on `val comment = dataSnapshot.getValue<Comment>()`

**Error:** *no type arguments expected for fun getValue: Any?*

Can someone please explain the meaning of this error and how to get around it.

Comment: What does error it prints in Logcat???

Comment: Error: no type arguments expected for fun getValue: Any?

Comment: I found the answer to this in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758680/4363563